# How to add Byobu as a Favorite in the Gnome Shell favorites bar

Tags: gnome, shortcuts, byobu, favorites

After every reboot, I click "Show Applications", look for Byobu, and click it.
**QUESTION: How to add it as a favorite?**

I tried to right-click and select "Add to Favorites", but the created shortcut starts a normal terminal, not Byobu.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The below solution has been tested on 18.04:

Check the content of the `/usr/share/applications` folder. There should be a file named `byobu.desktop`. If there is none, create one, with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Byobu Terminal
Comment=Advanced Command Line and Text Window Manager
Icon=byobu
Exec=gnome-terminal --app-id us.kirkland.terminals.byobu -e byobu
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;
X-GNOME-Gettext-Domain=byobu
```

Install dconf-editor if you don't have it.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Now run `dconf-editor`, navigate to `org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps` with it.  And add `'byobu.desktop'` to the Custom value array.

**Voilà!**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Very good first answer and never a need to apologize to answer.  Please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1038194/revisions) and remember that is English: "the" = "это" and "a" = "нечто" but before nearly every word!  **;-)**