# High RAM consumption in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, memory-leak

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It used to be fine before I started installing tools like elastic search and other stuff, but now I notice unusually high RAM consumption.

Here are screenshots of my System Monitor:

[image: System Monitor Processes tab]

[image: System Monitor Resources tab]

Here is the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`:

```
MemTotal:       16129344 kB
MemFree:         2286680 kB
MemAvailable:    3967360 kB
Buffers:          119744 kB
Cached:          2719044 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           610276 kB
Inactive:       11923068 kB
Active(anon):       8048 kB
Inactive(anon): 10646840 kB
Active(file):     602228 kB
Inactive(file):  1276228 kB
Unevictable:      913328 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
SwapFree:        2097148 kB
Dirty:               160 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      10608000 kB
Mapped:           600224 kB
Shmem:            960324 kB
KReclaimable:     121880 kB
Slab:             236708 kB
SReclaimable:     121880 kB
SUnreclaim:       114828 kB
KernelStack:       18128 kB
PageTables:        49624 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    10161820 kB
Committed_AS:   16875648 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       43976 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             6816 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      283816 kB
DirectMap2M:     6789120 kB
DirectMap1G:    10485760 kB
```

Comment: [See this answer ?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1373913/1460940)

Comment: Hello - so what's the specific problem here? "My applications use some memory" isn't really a problem that can be solved. You could start by running the following command to see which 10 processes take up most memory: `ps aux | (read h; echo "$h"; sort -nr -k 4) | head -11 | less -X -S -E`

Comment: You can also use `htop` to get a more realistic view of memory usage. `htop` color codes memory usage, so the green portion is "used", blue is "buffers" and yellow is "cache" (which is of course volatile, and will be given up when needed).

Comment: How many tabs do you have open in your web browser? Try quitting apps to see if memory is reclaimed. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.