# Random screen distortion and freeze in Ubuntu 20.04/22.04

Tags: 20.04, kernel, 22.04, display, freeze

My screen randomly becomes distorted and freeze in Ubuntu 20.04/22.04. After this only hard reboot works. I have been experiencing this for 2 months now and have tried several solutions but nothing helps. Also I can't find any error log in syslog, kern.log etc.

**P.S - This started happening after I upgraded my 4GB+4GB RAM to 8GB+8GB. It also occurs less frequently in Wayland than in Xorg**

Configurations

CPU: dual core Intel Core i3-5005U (-MT MCP-)
speed/min/max: 1597/500/1900 MHz Kernel: 5.15.0-57-generic x86_64 Up: 31m
Mem: 2427.1/15914.1 MiB (15.3%) Storage: 1.14 TiB (1.9% used) Procs: 232
Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13

Video Link - https://vimeo.com/789106089

I have already tried following solutions but no help :-

1. Re seating the RAMS
2. playing with few grub configurations like i915.enable_psr=0 etc
3. Disabling browser hardware accleration
4. Running memory test in the boot menu, everything is fine.

Any help in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I diagnose my issue, when I'm not sure if it is a hardware or software issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384357/how-do-i-diagnose-my-issue-when-im-not-sure-if-it-is-a-hardware-or-software-is)

Comment: I am sure this is not a hardware issue as I already did memtest, but last time I disabled hardware acceleration for chrome I didn't reboot so the issue reoccurred but after again disabling hardware acceleration and reboot, the issue hasn't reappeared for last 2 days